# ADB Sideload stuck on serving update.zip at 0%

Tags: adb, side-loading

I'm using `adb sideload update.zip` command, but it is stuck on `serving at 0% (Verifying update package ... on phone)`.

I tried `adb usb` command, but the error is closed. The device state is `sideload`.

**More details:**
I have a Samsung A03s (SM-A037F). Yesterday it suggested an android update. I accepted and after that, the phone was restarting repeatedly stuck in at the  **Samsung logo**.

- I downloaded the latest full update package (Build Number: A037FXXU2CVK7)and platform-tools_r33.0.3 as well.
- I also installed the latest Samsung USB driver.
- Then I pressed **power+volume-up** button to enter recovery mode. I selected `Apply update from ADB`

*EDIT 1*: I can now do a reset factory, but I need my photos and videos.

*EDIT 2*: When I use `adb logcat` , the result is just: `- waiting for device -` for a long time and nothing else

Comment: check current rom A037FXXU2CVK in recovery mode and csc, sw rev: b: in download mode. download proper ROM (not latest) according to the current ROM. extract files and double check HOME_CSC exist. if so, you can flash four files in Odin3 without wiping data (not CSC). if still no luck, flashing single partitions with mtkclient might possible.

Comment: Thank you @alecxs . I did what you mentioned at first, but no result. Would you please explain more about flashing single partition?

Comment: won't help either. Odin flashed successfully?

Comment: Yes, that was successful but did not solve the problem, however thanks again @alecxs

Comment: read back userdata partition with [mtkclient](https://github.com/bkerler/mtkclient) `python3 mtk r userdata userdata.img` from [pendrive](https://rufus.ie). run `fsck userdata.img` to repair f2fs file system. if mountable, flash back to userdata partition.

Comment: Thank you @alecxs
1- I used `python mtk r userdata userdata.img` instead of `python3 mtk r userdata userdata.img` , because python3 makes an error.
2- Using that command, I see `Preloader - [LIB]: ←[31mStatus: Handshake failed, retrying...←[0m` 
So, is there any solutions? Many thanks before.

Comment: connect phone when powered off, with both Volume keys pressed. make sure you can see VCOM preloader drivers installed in device manager. btw you need linux for the step after

Comment: Thank you again @alecxs . I installed the drivers, but the error has been changes : `usb_class - [LIB]: ←[31mCouldn't get device configuration.←[0m`

Comment: https://github.com/bkerler/mtkclient/issues/211 or use linux. you can boot the ready-to-use `re_livedvdV4.iso` from pendrive

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a factory reset?

For A30 the steps are

> **How to perform a hard reset on Samsung Galaxy A30 via recovery mode?**
>
> Follow these steps to perform a hard reset on your Samsung Galaxy A30 and reset your device to factory default settings.
>
> - **Turn off** your smartphone.
> - Press and hold **Volume up + Home + Power** buttons simultaneously till the device logo appears.
> - After the device logo , release **Power** button but hold the others a few more seconds.
> - Release all the buttons when **Recovery mode** screen appears.
> - Go to **Wipe Data / Factory Reset** option using **Volume Down** and press **Power** button to confirm it.
> - Go to **Yes –Delete All User Data** using **Volume Down** and press **Power** button to continue.
> - Recovery screen will appear after formatting process. Then, press the **Power** button on **Reboot System Now** to restart.

From [factoryreset.net](https://www.factoryreset.net/samsung-galaxy-a30-hard-reset/)

I am not associated with this site in any way.

Comment: If an Android updates goes wrong I assume side loading a full OTA firmware is an attempt to recover the phone without data loss, so I don't think a factory reset is what the OP wants...

Comment: Thank you dear Rohit. As dear Robert mentioned, I really need my data and don't want to do a reset factory. Thank again for editing my question